# Add new security policy in SElinux on Android 10

Tags: android, android-source, selinux, seandroid

I want witch `/dev/i2c-1` device to be outside the SELinux security policy on Android 10.

I have the source code for Android 10. I tried creating a `.te` file in `/device/thales/mt8768q/sepolicy/edgelab.te`

In foo.te, I added a similar example to the site: https://source.android.com/security/selinux/customize.

```
allow domain i2c-1_device:chr_file rw_file_perms
```

But, in compilation, this line generates an error.

UPDATE:

I add new line on `/device/manufacturer/device-name/BoardConfig.mk`:

```
BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS += device/thales/mt8768q/sepolicy
```

The error is:

```
#line 206
device/mediatek/mt6765/sepolicy/bsp/mnld.te:8:ERROR 'syntax error' at token 'role' on line 97225:
#line 2 "device/thales/mt8768q/sepolicy/edgelab.te"
allow domain i2c-1_device:chr_file { { getattr open read ioctl lock map } { open append write lock map } }role r;
checkpolicy:  error(s) encountered while parsing configuration
```

Maybe `i2c-1_device` is not a valid name, but I don't know how to refer to `/dev/i2c-1` in `.te` file.

Comment: Its impossible to help without you sharing the errorr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your should define your domain and label.

1. Define your dev_type (device/"manufacturer"/"device-name"/sepolicy/"your-filename".te):

   type i2c-1_device, dev_type;
2. Label file with your type (device/"manufacturer"/"device-name"/sepolicy/file_contexts):

   /dev/i2c-1/* u:object_r:i2c-1_device:s0
3. Define your rule (device/"manufacturer"/"device-name"/"your-filename".te):

   allow domain i2c-1_device:chr_file rw_file_perms

You'd better define your domain and restrict only your domain can access i2c-1_device. The [example](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/customize#example_policy) define an dhcp domain, it's an good example.